# Access 2007 Query to return latest date note from subquery

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables joined by `ProjectID` in Access 2007.  Table structure of primary table (A) is like

```
ProjectID | CustID
 1        |   5
 2        |   8
```

I have a secondary table (B) of notes on the ProjectID, structured like

```
ProjectNotesID | ProjectID |  Note    | CreateDate
---------------------------------------------------
 1             |  1        |  Note11  | 1/2/2015
 2             |  1        |  Note12  | 2/2/2015
 3             |  2        |  Note21  | 4/8/2015
 4             |  2        |  Note22  | 3/5/2015
```

I want to return all of, or part of, Table A, with the latest note of Table B, something like

```
ProjectID | CustID | Note    | CreateDate
------------------------------------------
 1        |  5     | Note12  |  2/2/2015 
 2        |  8     | Note21  |  4/8/2015
```

I can do (and have done) this with PHP & MySQL, but can't get it to work in Access 2007.  I can return the ProjectID and latest Note date by the following query in Access 2007

```
SELECT ProjectID, Max(CreateDate) AS MaxOfCreateDate
FROM Table B
GROUP BY ProjectID;
```

I have tried Unique Values, etc., but can't get the results I am looking for.

Thanks!

Pete

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.  First, I changed the query where I got the latest date, and instead got the max ProjectNotesID.  The query is ::

```
SELECT ProjectID, Max(ProjectNotesID) AS MaxOfProjectNotesID 
FROM Table B
GROUP BY ProjectID;
```

I then created a second query combining the above query and Table B, joining Query.MaxOfProjectNotesID <-> TableB.ProjectNotesID, and Query.ProjectID <-> TableB.ProjectID.  The second query pulls all values from TableB.